# Discussion about chat room that brings attention to relevant questions from other sites

Tags: discussion, tags, chat, other-se-sites

I made [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110113/whats-going-on-elsewhere) thinking that it would be as simple as spending 5 minutes adding feeds from Chem.SE, 5 minutes for Physics.SE, 2 minutes for ComputationalScience.SE, 2 minutes for Engineering.SE, and maybe some time on considering what to import from AI.SE, QuantumComputing.SE, Math.SE, MathOverflow.SE, Stats.SE, Biology.SE, DataScience.SE, OpenSource.SE, Astro.SE, and Space.SE.

**It turned out to be a much more difficult process than I ever imagined.**

So far I have added the following feeds from Chem.SE alone:

[image]

The following are other tags in Chem.SE that at least I personally am interested in (but they might not interest you):

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-chemistry 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thermodynamics  
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molecular-structure 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbitals 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-configuration 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/molecular-orbital-theory 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystal-structure 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transition-metals 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hybridization 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intermolecular-forces 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solid-state-chemistry 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entropy 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-energy 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chirality 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valence-bond-theory 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vsepr-theory 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinetic-theory-of-gases 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic-radiation 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemical-engineering 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semiconductors 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-organic-chemistry 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ligand-field-theory 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53510/how-are-van-der-waals-parameters-determined-experimentally 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88585/whats-the-longest-c-c-bond 
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-chemistry

It's going to be hard to decide which tags to add such that the room is not filling up with new questions every 30 seconds, while also making it so that none of us miss questions that we might find interesting.

Unfortunately all active questions from all the feeds I already added, are already landing in the chat room mostly simultaneously, so for the first couple weeks the room will look a bit overwhelming and we won't really have a clear idea of what it will look like in practice (when all the initial front loading is over and we see the questions being added in "real-time" as they get asked).

I know a lot of people will have objections to many of the tags I suggested above, because I added pretty much everything that I personally like. Instead of hearing all the different things that each person objects to, at the risk of others that object to the objection jumping in and playing ping-pong back-and-forth to debate whether or not to keep a tag, how about we hear from people if there are any specific tags that people ***absolutely do want*** to be in the feeds?

I don't expect anyone to answer or have any clear opinion on this until a couple weeks from now when we see what the chat room looks like once things there are settled a bit, but I'm writing this here now so that people can starting thinking about it!

On a related note: I wonder if anyone knows any way to get a graphical visualization of the connectivity matrix representing tags and how they're related to each other? I noticed that questions with tags like basis-set and multi-reference almost(?) 100% of the time also had the tag computational-chemistry or quantum-chemistry, so it wasn't necessary to add those tags (though I still did, since we would surely want anything that is missed by those tags too). However this would help in making the decisions for some of the suggested tags I didn't add yet, because maybe all the questions we're interested in from that tag are already covered by another tag.

Comment: Not a full fledged version of what you want, but the if you click a tag, it will bring up a list of all questions with that tag. Along the side, it will have a list of "Related tags" with the number of posts that have both tags. In principle, you could probably write a query in the SE data explorer to get a full connectivity matrix of tags, though I don't know if this has been done before or if it is worth the work to export/graph/analyze/etc.

Comment: Some good news: While at first the room looked a bit overwhelming, in the last 18 hours only 2 new questions showed up, so the number of questions per day is quite manageable so far. Perhaps some more tags can be added (though maybe first from other SEs before returning to Chem.SE). I'm keeping an eye on it for now, and may wait a bit more before adding more tags.